# Hello world shellcode gets executed correctly but prints nothing to stdout

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, shellcode

I've got the following simple assembly code in `hello.asm`:

```
section .text:
    global _start

    _start:

    jmp short ender

    starter:

    ; clean registers
    xor rax, rax
    xor rbx, rbx
    xor rcx, rcx
    xor rdx, rdx

    ; writes 'hello\n' to stdout
    mov al, 0x04 ; 4 = syscall number of sys_write
    mov bl, 0x01 ; 1 = file descriptor of stdout
    pop rcx      ; points to 'hello\n'
    mov dl, 0x06 ; writes 6 characters
    int 0x80

    ; exits with status 5
    xor rax, rax
    mov al, 0x01 ; 1 = syscall number of sys_exit
    xor rbx, rbx
    mov bl, 0x05 ; 5 = exit status number
    int 0x80

    ender:

    call starter
    db 'hello',0x0a
```

Inspired by [an article on shellcoding](http://www.vividmachines.com/shellcode/shellcode.html), the assembly code pushes `hello\n` on the stack, writes it to the standard outputs, then exits with code `5`.

I can compile it and run it successfully:

```sh
$ nasm -f elf64 hello.asm
$ ld hello.o -o hello
$ ./hello
hello
```

Using `objdump -D hello` and a short python script, I can extract the related shellcode string and test it with this simple C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char* shellcode = "\xeb\x21\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xdb\x48\x31\xc9\x48\x31\xd2\xb0\x04\xb3\x01\x59\xb2\x06\xcd\x80\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x48\x31\xdb\xb3\x05\xcd\x80\xe8\xda\xff\xff\xff\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x0a";

void main() {
    (*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
}
```

## The issue

The expected output of `./test-shellcode` is `hello\n` with exit status 5, just like when running the compiled assembly. However, the program simply doesn't output anything, but still exits with a status of 5!

After debugging it with GDB, I observe that the program executes the shellcode as expected. Particularly, this section that is supposed to write `hello\n` to stdout is executed without errors and the content of `rcx` is the address of the `hello\n` string:

```
   0x5555555546d6:  mov    $0x4,%al
   0x5555555546d8:  mov    $0x1,%bl
   0x5555555546da:  pop    %rcx
   0x5555555546db:  mov    $0x6,%dl
   0x5555555546dd:  int    $0x80
```

But despite the fact that `sys_write` is apparently correctly called and is executed without errors, ***nothing*** is written to the standard output.

## Why?

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: Linux 4.15.0-48-generic, Ubuntu 51,  x86_64

Comment: Do not use `int 0x80` in 64-bit code especially when you are passing addresses that are stack based. You need to use the `syscall` instruction and the 64-bit System V ABI Kernel calling convention. `Int 0x80` will only see the bottom 32-bits of the RCX register (ECX). Stack addresses in Linux can't be represented in a 32-bit register so the address `int 0x80` sees for your string isn't where you think it is.

Comment: As for the reason the standalone version works - because in standalone executable the string address that ends up in RCX is part of the `.data` section and in your case the addresses in the `.data` section can be represented in a 32-bit register (ECX). When run from the stack the addresses aren't properly represented by just looking at ECX so `int 0x80` silently fails with a bad address.

Comment: You can get a table of the Linux 64-bit syscall system numbers and their parameters in Ryan Chapman's table. The `syscall` instruction uses different system call numbers than `int 0x80` and parameters are passed in different registers: http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64

Comment: Your stand-alone version is a static executable so it's loaded in the low 2GB of virtual address space where the addresses fit in 32-bit for `int 0x80` to work.  When you inject it into a PIE executable, `sys_write` returns `-EFAULT` because `ecx` isn't a valid address (only RCX is, but you used the 32-bit ABI).

Comment: Also, 64-bit code doesn't need to use jmp/call/pop.  You can just jump over your string and use a RIP-relative `lea rsi, [rel msg]`.  (Although that's not actually shorter, with LEA being 7 bytes vs. call+pop being 6.)